# Return the column names from an empty MySQL query result

Tags: python, python-3.x, mysql-connector

I'm using Python 3.2.3, with the MySQL/Connector 1.0.7 module. Is there a way to return the column names, if the MySQL query returns an empty result?

For example. Say I have this query:

```
SELECT 
`nickname` AS `team`,
`w` AS `won`,
`l` AS `lost`
WHERE `w`>'10'
```

Yet, if there's nobody over 10, it returns nothing, obviously. Now, I know I can check if the result is `None`, but, **can I get MySQL to return the column name and a NULL value for it?**

If you're curious, the reason I'm wondering if this is possible, is because I'm dynamically building dict's based on the column names. So, the above, would end up looking something like this if nobody was over 10...

```
[{'team':None,'won':None,'lost':None}]
```

And looks like this, if it found 3 teams over 10...

```
[{'team':'Tigers','won':14,'lost':6},
 {'team':'Cardinals','won':12,'lost':8},
 {'team':'Giants','won':15,'lost':4}]
```

If this kind of thing is possible, then I won't have to write a ton of exception checks all over the code in case of empty dict's all over the place.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a DESC table_name first, you should get the column names in the first column

Also you already know the keys in the dict so you can construct yourself and then append things to it if the result has values.

```
[{'team':None,'won':None,'lost':None}]
```

But what I fail to see why you need this. If you have a `list of dictionaries`, I am guessing you will have for loop operations. For loop will not do anything to a empty list, so you would not have to bother about exception checks

If you have to do something like `result[0]['team']` then you should definitely check if `len(result)>0`